# Current value to an HTML input statement

Tags: html

I need to input a number using:
`<label for="input1">Input 1"</label> <input type="number" id="input1" name="input1">`
but I need to also display the current value of that number. So if the current value is 23.6, I want the user to see this value in the input box.

I have tried a number of methods using javascript but am unsure how to pick up the current value.

Comment: Since the question is only tagged with HTML: `<input type="number" id="input1" name="input1" value="23.6">`

Comment: In the research that you did before asking this question, none of the results for *"How to set the value of an HTML input element?"* got you any closer?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to also display the current value" or "I want the user to see this value in the input box"? The value a user inputs is displayed in that same input element. Do you perhaps mean after submission/navigation?

Comment: I want the input box to work like a numeric dialog box in windows. In other words when displayed it shows the current value of that variable. When the user edits that value and after being submitted it shows the new value.

Comment: It was, as usual, easy when you know how. In the script getValues function I added the line:

Answer (score -1):

I changed the code because i think this is better:

```html
<span id="s-i" style="position: absolute;" onClick="document.getElementById('input1').focus();">Input 1&#8243;</span>

<input type="text" oninput="input()" id="input1" name="input1" style="color: white;">

<script>
function input(){
   document.getElementById("s-i").innerHTML = "Input 1&#8243;"
 +  document.getElementById("input1").value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').slice(0, 18);
}

</script>
```

Comment: It was, as usual, easy when you know how. In the script getValues function I added the line: document.getElementById("input1").value = myObj.numValue; Now the "input1" field always shows the current number.